# Segmentation fault when using strcpy to copy a "string" into a struct member char*

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have a pointer to my `struct gsa_sentence` which has a struct member of type `char*` called `untouched_sentence`.

My goal is to copy a line from a file, into this struct variable using strcpy, but I am getting a segmentation fault on the strcpy function call.

structure:

```
typedef struct gsa_sentence{

    char *untouched_sentence;
    char *sentence_id;
    char mode;
    int fix;
    int sv_1;
    int sv_2;
    int sv_3;
    int sv_4;
    int sv_5;
    int sv_6;
    int sv_7;
    int sv_8;
    int sv_9;
    int sv_10;
    int sv_11;
    int sv_12;
    int pdop;
    int hdop;
    int vdop;

}gsa_sentence;
```

strcpy call:

```
   gsa_sentence* gsa;

   gsa = malloc(sizeof(gsa_sentence));
   printf("%s", line);
    if(gsa != NULL){
       strncpy(gsa->untouched_sentence, line, strlen(line));
       printf("%s", gsa->untouched_sentence);
        }
```

I have used strcpy elsewhere in my code and it works fine, I cannot figure out what is going on.

The gdb debugger says it's definately on the strcpy function call

Comment: hard to say when you've omitted your definition of `line`. That said, you should avoid using `strcpy`. Use the safer `strncpy`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strcpy is attempting to copy characters into an uninitialized character buffer.  You'll want to malloc space for `untouched sentence`," as well, or reassign `untouched sentence` to the memory address of `line`.

Alternatively, you could change the definition of the struct to include allocated memory by default:

```
typedef struct gsa_sentence{

    char untouched_sentence[50];
    char sentence_id[50];
...
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have worked :) sorry im really bad at C!

Comment: That works as long as the sentence length is less than 50. The best way to do this is with `strdup`

Comment: No worries, Chris.  C is difficult for everyone, at first, due to memory management concepts just like this one.

Comment: @Russell im slowly grasping it, thanks for taking the time to help me. Im used to Java, so this is a weird concept.

Answer (score 3):

You need to allocate memory for `gsa->untouched_sentence` before copying data. You are only allocating memory for the structure itself.

Answer (score 2):

You have to allocate memory to gsa->untouched_sentence

```
gsa->untouched_sentence = malloc ( strlen ( line ) + 1 );
```

Answer (score -1):

You must allocate space for your string: all characters, plus delimiter.

`malloc (sizeof (gsa))` does NOT do this: "sizeof (gsa)" just returns enough for a pointer - not your entire string.

'malloc (sizeof (gsa_sentence))`or 'malloc (sizeof (gsa_sentence)+1)` would be better.  But I'm not sure that's what you want, either.

Comment: i have updated my code, but i am still getting the seg fault. im beyond confused :/